# Gnuplot, pm3d and surfaces

Tags: plot, gnuplot, geometry-surface

I have a question about pm3d and gnuplot. I want to plot two different surfaces with two different pm3d styles. How can i do that? Is it possible? I tried with multiplot but in that case surfaces will overlap and i cannot rotate the graph. Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: The only way I can think of is to use four columns for `splot`, in which case the fourth column is a separate palette-mapped gray value. Then you need to construct a single palette which contains one palette in one half and the other palette in the other half and then map your two surfaces to use only the respective half of the palette. It is possible, but requires some fiddling :-)

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example with pseudo data:

```
reset 
set xrange[0:1]
set yrange[0:1]
set cbrange[0:1]
set palette defined (0 'green', 1 'red', 1 'blue', 2 'white')
set isosamples 100
set samples 100
set pm3d depthorder
set view 60,335
splot '++' using 1:2:2:(0.5*$2) with pm3d title 'red -> green',\
      '++' using 1:2:1:(0.5*(1+$1)) with pm3d title 'blue -> white'
```

Result:
[image]

To use data instead of these pseudo data generated by '++' you can use `stats` to determine the data ranges and scale the surface colors accordingly to `[0:0.5]` for one, and to `[0.5:1]` for the other.

This concept with the different color ranges to incorporate two palettes in one does work only for data files (including pseudo data files). To plot two spheres beneath each other with different colors, one can first produce a data file, which is later used for `pm3d` plotting:

```
reset 
# generate the sphere data
set samples 100
set isosamples 100
set parametric
set urange[0:2*pi]
set vrange[0:pi]
set table 'spheres.dat'
r = 0.25
splot r*cos(u)*sin(v),r*sin(u)*sin(v),r*cos(v) with lines
unset table
unset parametric

# plot the generated data set
set xrange[-1:1]
set yrange[-1:1]
set cbrange[-1:3]
set palette defined (0 'black', 1 'green', 1 'black', 2 'red')

set pm3d depthorder
unset colorbox
unset key
set ticslevel 0
set view 19,34
splot 'spheres.dat' using ($1-0.5):2:3:($3/r) with pm3d, \
      '' using ($1+0.5):2:3:($3/r + 2) with pm3d
```

The result is
[image]

Comment: Thank you. In my case i have to plot two surfaces but with more than one value of z. For example i want to plot two spheres in the xy plane and i want to assign red color to one and green to the other.

Comment: I want to plot the spheres with functions, not with data file

Comment: @PaoloUsai Well, I do also have more than one `z` value. You should read a bit in the manual about the special filename `++` and about the `using` statement. And should the spheres be completely red, or shaded e.g. from red to white?

Comment: Now i can plot the spheres with different colors but i still cannot make this using function. It seems that this procedure needs the datafile