# Multiple colorbars in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, palette

I'm trying to plot two data series in the same graph with multiplot. I would like each of the two data series to be plotted with a different palette. So far I've been trying with multiplot,

```
set multiplot layout 1,1
#
set palette rgb 21,22,23
splot "S1"    using ($1):($2):($3):($5)  with points pt 7 ps 3 palette notitle, \
      "S1"    using ($1):($2):($3):($5)  with impulses linecolor "black" notitle
#
set palette rgb 23,28,3
splot "S1" using ($1):($2):($3):($5)     with points pt 7 ps 3 palette notitle, \
      "S2" using ($1):($2):($3):($5)     with impulses linecolor "black" notitle
#     
unset multiplot
```

however, I can not visualize in the X11 terminal the two series at the same time.
Any idea?

Comment: What exactly is not working? Using two different palettes? For me it works fine with 4.6.0. Or do you want to display both colorboxes? In that case you need to set the size and position of both colorboxes manually with `set colorbox user size ... position ...`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm working with 4.6.4 under OSX. The problem ariese when I rotate the splot with arrow keys.

Comment: More precisely, after I run the script, I see only the first series plotted, and after the rotation I see only the second series.

Comment: Thats a general problem with `multiplot`. Gnuplot can refresh only the last plot in a multiplot. To circumvent that for an interactive terminal, you can define two palettes in one, like shown [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18249166/2604213), and then you can plot all in a single `splot` command, but you must map the color values to the correct region in the palette.

Comment: Thank you. So this is an issue related to an interactive terminal.

Comment: Concerning the rotation, yes.