# Two plots on the same graph

Tags: gnuplot

I am using Gnuplot 5.0. 
Here are my plots:
[image: g.png]
[image: f.png]
Can they be shown on the same graph with different palette defined?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: check here for similar answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21196047/gnuplot-can-you-use-two-different-palettes-worship

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/18249166/2604213