# Ploting multiple spheres in gnuplot from a file

Tags: gnuplot

I have a file with 5 columns (x,y,z,r,c) that contains on each line the coordinates of a sphere,its radius and its color (a number or a letter to determine the color, I can change it) . Could you please help me to plot these spheres in gnuplot?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18243527/gnuplot-pm3d-and-surfaces

Answer (score 3):

```
set palette rgb 7,5,15
splot 'spheres.dat' using 1:2:3:4:5 with points pt 7 ps var lc palette  notitle
```

visit http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/pm3dcolors.html to see how to set the palette you want to use.